# Uploading large files to web-server even if browser closed

Tags: web-applications, files, upload

I need to permit users to upload large files to my web-server even if the browser is closed. How can I implement this functionality. I have gone through the feasibility of google drive app but it dose't provide the details of on-going uploads.

Comment: What can be said is to not use a browser, if the browser is closed every uploaded managed by it will be canceled. Maybe allow them to write on some shared directories and link the path to the app ? 3Gb is ... really big.

Comment: Your users might consider using a command line HTTP client like `curl` or `wget` or use FTP... But once the browser is closed, nothing (related to it) is running on the client machine, which might be powered off.

Comment: If the same user is often uploading on the same browser similar large files to the same server, you might consider using some distributed version control system like [git](http://git-scm.com/) or some differential uploader like `rsync`; in both cases only *differences* (or *deltas*) are sent.

Comment: @Walfrat the files are Uncompressed RGB  video files, there will be multiple files also. which may varies from 3 to 40 gb .

Comment: The bottleneck would always be the network. No software solution can change that.

Comment: Or use some peer to peer solutions. @BasileStarynkevitch Even if the network follow, it's not like the whole company will be on SSD Drives, so the very max you can get is like 30MB/s. Which make already 20MN of just reading the file locally for the 40Gb file. ebinmanuval : you should at least search for some compression of your video that doesn't loss data, i think the term for that is `loseless compression`. Handle 40Gb file is... way too much.

Comment: If you have control over which browsers will be supported, I would recommend investigating Service Workers. Background syncing is one of the many alleged features, though I've never tried it myself.

Comment: @JeffreySweeney Service Workers  will only stay alive as long as the owner is alive. So closing the tab halt the Service Workers.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to look into webdav. This uses http PUT requests to upload files to a URL. With nearly all OSes, you can simply drag and drop the file into a file explorer window, or map the webdav URL to a local directory/drive letter.